# "Correct" way to communicate with a local Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services

What's the 'correct', or at least 'typical' way to communicate with a Windows service running locally?

I can see that it's pretty trivial to use WCF to open a HTTP or TCP endpoint, but both these are *really* network protocols.

What protocol should I choose to invoke methods and receive responses from a local windows service?

Comment: Depends on the service component itself (and what needs to be done)..

Comment: @user2864740 cheer, what are the service options?  I thought there was just the standard Windows Services?  The ones you see in the `services.msc`.

Comment: Is this question about "a service" or a *particular* service? There is no one way that the standard [windows] services work.

Comment: I new Windows Service I'm writing, I'm wondering what's the best was to allow another application to talk to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

- Socket communications (TCP, HTTP, or other): even though you say they are network protocols the advantage is that you might already know them
- Named pipes: this is a good option for communication between processes running in the same node: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx
- shared memory: this is the fastest
- Other third party, higher level, library like Thrift which uses sockets

Comment: I don't need blazing fast speed, just _good enough_, I  guess named pipes would be the most secure option then, unless you can think of any potential problems?

Comment: @BanksySan, I would also use named pipes. Microsoft provides some examples you can copy and modify. It has some little tricks that you can learn as you do it. At first glimpse, from what you say it seems the best option.

Comment: Hi Guys, I was reading the answer carefully and on regards of Named Pipes, I understood that for a duplex process communication across different computers , it is suitable, but recently I was reading a new API called SignalR or at least new for me... I am wondering if this is something alternative to named pipes or how does it compares with it?

Comment: @willyMon Maybe you can analyze it and add another response. That will help all of us to learn more.

Comment: Actually I decided to create a sample test with the following configuration: a website with a button that invokes an operation from a Hub Class. then I created a windows service and by using SignalR client I was able to subscribe to events on the website i already published in internet. the result was a duplex communcation very fast and with less or minimun effort.